# Find closing parenthesis with regex in r

Tags: r, regex

I have several strings with open and unclosed parenthesis. I managed to remove the opening parenthesis (if there is no closing one), but I do not manage to remove the closing parenthesis if there is no opening one. I want to leave those with matching parenthesis alone

```
string1 = "This (is solved"
string2 = "This is (fine)"
string3 = "This is the problem)"
```

This is what I was able to remove the first Problem case with (Opening parenthesis but no opening)

```
str_remove(data, "[(](?!.*[)])")
```

But I cannot seem to turn it around. The following grabs all closing parenthesis, but not the one without an oping.

```
"(?!.*[(])[)]"
```

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Do you need to support nested paired parentheses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not need to handle nested paired (balanced) parentheses, you can use

```r
gsub("(\\([^()]*\\))|[()]", "\\1", string)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lZx00c/3). *Details*:

- `(\([^()]*\))` - Group 1 (`\1` refers to this group value): `(`, then zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`, and then a `)` char
- `|` - or
- `[()]` - a `(` or `)` char.

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/JpJyX8):

```r
x <- c("This (is solved", "This is (fine)", "This is the problem)")
gsub("(\\([^()]*\\))|[()]", "\\1", x)
# => [1] "This is solved"      "This is (fine)"      "This is the problem"
```

If the parentheses can be nested, you can use

```r
gsub("(\\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\\))|[()]", "\\1", string, perl=TRUE)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lZx00c/4). *Details*:

- `(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))` - Group 1:

  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `(?:[^()\n]++|(?1))*` - zero or more sequences of either one or more chars other than `(` and `)`, or the whole Group 1 pattern that is recursed
  - `\)` - a `)` char
- `|[()]` - or a `(` / `)` char.

Comment: Haha! Thank you! Like magic!

Comment: FYI: I think there is a "\" missing in the last line, ("\\1") just in case someone else uses it. It made smileys in my text where the open parenthesis were.

Comment: @H.Stevens Right, forgot to escape the backslash.